# Android ResultReceiver across packages

Tags: android, ipc, android-service

I have an activity in package A (SignerClient), and a service in package B (MyService)

The activity's resultreceiver:

```
private ResultReceiver resultreceiver = new ResultReceiver(null) {
            @Override
            protected void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {
            ...
            }
        };
```

Starting the service:

```
Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.STARTSERVICE");
intent.putExtra("resultreceiver", resultreceiver);            
startService(intent);
```

Receiving end:

```
 ResultReceiver rr = (ResultReceiver) intent.getParcelableExtra("resultreceiver");
```

Doing this when client and server are in the same package works fine. But in this case i get:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[MyService]
android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: com.example.cryptoclient.SignerClient$1
at android.os.Parcel.readParcelable(Parcel.java:1883)
at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:1771)
at android.os.Parcel.readMapInternal(Parcel.java:2008)
at android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:208)
at android.os.Bundle.getParcelable(Bundle.java:1100)
at android.content.Intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.java:3396)
at org.axades.service.MyService.onHandleIntent(MyService.java:28)
at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:59)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
```

What am I missing? Is my idea even possible?

Comment: Since this topic is quite old : This class from the support library was added in package `android.os` from android Lollipop onward, and the issue seems solved in the process. Make sure to import the right one... (see answer below)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, your idea is possible. The `ClassNotFoundException` exception is thrown because you are trying to unparcel a class that was created in a different process by a different `ClassLoader`.

`ResultReceiver` class implements `Parcelable` interface which is suitable for inter-process calls (IPC), however to read your object in the service you need to use the same ClassLoader, that was used for object creation in the client application (i.e. in the activity). To get that ClassLoader on the service side, call [`createPackageContext`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#createPackageContext%28java.lang.String,%20int%29) method passing client package name and [`CONTEXT_INCLUDE_CODE`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#CONTEXT_INCLUDE_CODE)|[`CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY) combination of flags. This will return client Context object from which the correct ClassLoader object can be obtained.

Example:

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
  try {

// assuming SignerClient activity is located in the package "com.example.client.A"
    Context context = createPackageContext("com.example.client.A", Context.CONTEXT_INCLUDE_CODE | Context.CONTEXT_IGNORE_SECURITY);
    ClassLoader cl = context.getClassLoader();

    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    bundle.setClassLoader(cl);
    ResultReceiver rr = bundle.getParcelable("resultreceiver");

//... your interaction with ResultReceiver ...
    rr.send(1, null);   // will result in a onReceiveResult call in the client activity

  } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
    Log.e("MyService", "SignerClient package context was not found", e);
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
  }
  return START_STICKY;
}
```

I've just used it in my code - works like a charm.

**UPDATE**
However I suggest to consider using `Messenger` instead of `ResultReceiver`. It implements `Parcelable` interface and does not need to be extended thus the ClassLoader issue isn't possible. And it's also [recommended in the official documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Messenger).

**UPDATE 2**
In case you still prefer to use `ResultReceiver` take a look at [Robert's answer in this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12183036/648313). It looks cleaner and simpler than hacky context manipulations.

Comment: I think you're wrong here, according to http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Message.html#getData() it seems you still need to use a class loader.

Comment: @MiroKropacek Not really. In case of Messenger you need to set a class loader only to instantiate an object passed from one process to another through the Messenger (i.e. if you send to Process A in the `Message.object` field an instance of class defined in Process B). The Messenger itself doesn't require class loader to be set and can be safely used to pass primitives and objects of types loaded by system class loader, like String, Point etc.

Comment: The docs recommend IntentService over MessengerService (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html), which makes sense for one-off requests where you don't need an ongoing connection.  It doesn't make sense that they don't say how to actually send results outside of the special case of being in the same app, though.

Answer (score 29):

I wanted to use a `ResultReceiver` across packages and having to load the other package's context just didn't seem right to me... after all, the receiving package doesn't need to know the particular subclass of `ResultReceiver` used, it just needs to be able to call `send()` and let the IPC binder magic happen.  Needing to have the particular subclass available seems like a design flaw.

There is a workaround:

```
public static ResultReceiver receiverForSending(ResultReceiver actualReceiver) {
    Parcel parcel = Parcel.obtain();
    actualReceiver.writeToParcel(parcel,0);
    parcel.setDataPosition(0);
    ResultReceiver receiverForSending = ResultReceiver.CREATOR.createFromParcel(parcel);
    parcel.recycle();
    return receiverForSending;
}
```

This code converts your instance of some subclass of `ResultReceiver` into a instance of `ResultReceiver` itself, which nonetheless still sends results to your original `actualReceiver`.  The `receiverForSending` can be sent in an `Intent` extra to another package and can be unmarshalled just fine.

Comment: thank you! Very good implementation! Indeed, to load some package's context is bad idea when we can use this.

Comment: I'm not even using IPC and I still had to use this approach. Good solution....and rather unfortunate.

Comment: Worked perfectly in my IPC scenario :)

Comment: Absolutely brilliant!

Comment: This seems to work better with the android.os.ResultReceiver implementation, no RestrictedApi violations that way

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, I had this error only with `android.support.v4.os.ResultReceiver`. Changing the imports to `android.os.ResultReceiver` made the ipc results work at once. No workaround needed!

Comment: `android.os.ResultReceiver` was added in API 3: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/ResultReceiver.html